# Convert from KB to bit

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, bit

I have csv file contain values in KB like this

```
8.0703125
7.401367188
8.96875
8.17578125
7.552734375
7.301757813
8.1015625
7.692382813
8.221679688
8.052734375
7.854492188
7.548828125
```

How can I convert these values to bits ?

Comment: 1kilobyte = 1024 bytes, 1 byte = 8 bits

Comment: ...because you have not shown any effort in solving that task, nor any effort is visible of research (since this has surely been asked before). The tooltip of the downvote button explains its meaning *"This question does not show any research effort..."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read from the `.csv` file and convert to float then convert to `bits` like below:

```
import csv

with open("Book1.csv") as fp:
    reader = csv.reader(fp)
    next(reader, None)  # skip the headers
    data_read = [row[0] for row in reader]

def KB_to_bits(x):
#     return x*8000
    return round(x*8000,2)

list(map(KB_to_bits,(map(float,data_read))))
```

Output:

```
[64562.5,
 59210.94,
 71750.0,
 65406.25,
 60421.88,
 58414.06,
 64812.5,
 61539.06,
 65773.44,
 64421.88,
 62835.94,
 60390.62]
```

Or you can use `pandas` like below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('Book1.csv', header=None)  

def KB_to_bits(x):
#     return x*8000
    return round(x*8000,2)

df.apply(KB_to_bits)
```

Output:

```
    0
0   64562.50
1   59210.94
...
11  60390.62
```